# Check arguments of sinon stub in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, sinon

I have a unit test that checks arguments of the function.

```
it('Should return product from DB', () => {
  stub(ProductModel, 'findById').returns({
    lean: stub().returns({ total: 12 }),
  });


  getProduct(product_id);

  expect((ProductModel.findById as any).firstCall.args[0]).to.equal('product_id');
});
```

My question is: Is there any other better way to do it? I have to always cast to `any` to avoid getting error.
I have also tried `stubFunc.calledWith(args)`, but in a result I get only true/false instead of expected/actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Assertions API](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/assertions/) of `sinon`. Besides, the return value of `sinon.stub()` method is a `sinon` stub. So you can use this return value instead of using `ProductModel.findById`. By doing this, you don't need to type cast to `any` explicitly.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { ProductModel } from "./model";

function getProduct(id: string) {
  return ProductModel.findById(id).lean();
}

export { getProduct };
```

`model.ts`:

```js
class ProductModel {
  public static findById(id: string): { lean: () => { total: number } } {
    return { lean: () => ({ total: 0 }) };
  }
}

export { ProductModel };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { stub, assert } from "sinon";
import { getProduct } from "./";
import { ProductModel } from "./model";

describe("60034220", () => {
  it("should pass", () => {
    const product_id = "1";
    const leanStub = stub().returns({ total: 12 });
    const findByIdStub = stub(ProductModel, "findById").returns({
      lean: leanStub,
    });
    getProduct(product_id);
    assert.calledWithExactly(findByIdStub, product_id);
    assert.calledOnce(leanStub);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
60034220
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (28ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |       90 |      100 |    66.67 |    94.74 |                   |
 index.test.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 model.ts      |    66.67 |      100 |    33.33 |       80 |                 3 |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/60034220